# How to convert UTF8 with BOM to UTF16 LE

Tags: c, linux, unix, unicode

How can I convert UTF8 with BOM to UTF16LE? I already used iconv -f UTF8 -t UTF16 TEST.xml > TEST2.xml. When checking the contents using hex editor it shows prints both the UTF8 and UTF16 (EF BB BF FF FE).

Answer (score 1):

I would write a script for this.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Usage: convert FILE ENCODING
# Converts UTF-8 with BOM to target encoding
bom=`printf '\xef\xbb\xbf'`
if test "$bom" != `head -c 3 -- "$1"` ; then
    echo 1>&2 'error: no BOM found.'
    exit 1
fi
tail -c +3 <"$1" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t "$2"
```